# Accessing Azure Key Vault from a third party service

Tags: security, azure

Is it somehow possible to access the Azure Key Vault and pick a secret inside the vault to use it in another service. The goal is to store secret values for 3rd party application to use. At least, I am trying to test this with Postman, but I am trying to figure out the best way to access key vault via GET.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while waiting for the answer, I got some dig information that you can access Key Vault only after authenticating via Azure AD. Once the authentication is successful and Access Token is acquired, you can pass that token in the Authorization header as bearer token along with the GET call to retrieve information from Key Vault.

Link to Microsoft answer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/648673/accessing-azure-key-vault-with-3rd-party-service-u.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).